# How to make the words left justified without using table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to achieve the format in the picture.[image]
But when I use tabular, indentation appears.
How to solve this?

```
\subsection*{Time allowed for this section}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
Reading time before commencing work: & five minutes \\
Working time: & fifty minutes
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}` will remove the padding at either side of the `tabular`.

Comment: You may also need `\noindent`, if the `tabular` is the first thing in a paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can use the `flushleft` environment, but here you want some alignment, so I would suggest using `tabbing`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Time allowed for this section}

\begin{tabbing}
Reading time before commencing work: \= five minutes \\
Working time: \> fifty minutes
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

The `\=` in the first line sets the tab stop, `\>` in the second line moves to the tab stop.